# Not able to understand the how bigger chunks data is loaded into RAM in external merge sorting

Tags: algorithm, sorting, memory-management, mergesort

Today my friend asked me:

> Write a program to sort millions of element in your list but memory size is very small. It cannot hold more than 100 elements.

I was reading about `external merge sort` from the wikipedia article [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting), according to it:

> External sorting is required when the data being sorted do not fit
>   into the main memory of a computing device (usually RAM) and instead
>   they must reside in the slower external memory (usually a hard drive).
>   External sorting typically uses a hybrid sort-merge strategy. In the
>   sorting phase, chunks of data small enough to fit in main memory are
>   read, sorted, and written out to a temporary file. In the merge phase,
>   the sorted subfiles are combined into a single larger file.

Suppose we have a RAM which can only hold `2 chunks` of data and we have `6 chunks` of data to sort. Please see the below diagram:

[image: link]

Since our memory can hold `2 chunks of data` so the first `step 1` sounds plausible since we are sorting only pairs of numbers (5,6), (3,4) (1,2). In the `step 2` we merge the data and now our chunk size is `4`. My question is how do you now load this `4 chunk of data` into memory now? Since your memory cannot accept more than 2 chunks of data then how do you load and sort them? How did you sort while merging chunks of data here? I have visited several links, but not able to understand this concept.

You must be performing some kind of sorting while merging the data as well right? This question might sound dumb, but I am not able to understand it and will appreciate if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My confusion is cleared now:

> If you see the pseudo for `merge sort` if the two list are stored then
>   merging them will take only *O(1)* time only. You can see that Merge
>   only needs *O(1)* memory to merge two sorted lists, even if the sorted
>   lists are stored in external storage -- it never needs to load the
>   input lists into memory in their entirety.

If you see the visualization of `merge sort` [link](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/ComparisonSort.html) once the list is sorted then it is all about merging, we do not require any temporary space now.

Answer (score 0):

There are (3, 4, 5, 6) and (1, 2). Now compare two chunk data.
first pointer indicates first chunk data, second pointer indicates second chunk data. Then, first pointer indicates 3 and second pointer indicates 1.
Compare 3 and 1, 1 is small so 1 is saved and out of memory.
first pointer is same, second pointer indicates 2 and so on.

Not just load the entire size of chunk data. It was sorted so we just know first number(smallest) that each of chunk data and comparing just two number.